# Fill form from URL - postget or how?

Tags: url, post, hyperlink, get

Its not my site `http://kongressm.ru/marathon_bsk_web2`

I want to enter this site with url, that automatically fill only one text form on site.

How I can do it?

For example `http://kongressm.ru/marathon_bsk_web2?formParams[email]=MYTEXT` doesnt work

form html:

```
<div data-param="form/items/parts/emailField" data-item-name="emailField" data-title="Элемент" data-animation-mode="no" style="margin-bottom: 4px; border-radius: ; " data-setting-editable="true" class="builder-item part-userField ">
    <div id="fieldStandard1066146" data-hide-filled="0">
        <div class="field-content">
            <input type="text" maxlength="60" class="f-input" placeholder="Электронная почта" name="formParams[email]" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From what I get from the question, you're trying to pass in GET parameters to fill the form on the page.

This really depends on how the site's been made. Unless there's an explicit code in the back end of the site which allows such functionality, it's hard to implement that.

However, you can always simulate the form submission, if you know the target URL, request method, and the required parameters.

The Python `requests` library should do, or tools like [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) or [Postman](https://getpostman.com) should come in handy.

PS: In Insomnia, send the request under `Multipart Form` along with the form parameters.

Should work.